# Template converting constructor with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++

It is possible to replace the two constructors in this program with a single template constructor with perfect forwarding?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

using Mymap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_set<std::string>>;

class A {
    Mymap n_;
public:
    A(Mymap&& n) 
        : n_{std::move(n)} 
    {}

    A(Mymap& n) 
        : n_{n} 
    {}

    // doesn't compile
    //template <typename T>
    //A(T<Mymap::value_type>&& n)
    //    : n_{std::forward(n)}
    //{}
};

int main() {
    A a1{{{"C", {"A", "B"}}}};

    Mymap m{{{"C", {"A", "B"}}}};
    A a2{m};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Mymap` is inexpensive to move, then pass by value is often preferred:

```
A(Mymap n) : n_(std::move(n)) {}
```

Otherwise, you have to fall back on the ugly solution:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Mymap, std::decay_t<T>>>>
A(T&& n) : n_(std::forward<T>(n)) {}
```

(Arguably, `std::remove_cvref_t` fits the intent better than `std::decay_t`. You can use it starting in C++20.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I [can't get this template to work](https://godbolt.org/z/SEL7Ih) as the single constructor.

Comment: @wally yes, it will not work when you pass a braced-init-list. For that reason you may indeed want to keep both constructors, or use a single by-value constructor.

Comment: Ok, the single by-value constructor [does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/Vjpc0V). But won't this 'hollow out'  `Mymap m` and render it less useful later in the program?

Comment: @wally if you pass in an lvalue, a copy is made and then the constructor moves from the copy, so the original argument is not affected

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I should have thought a bit more before typing.

Comment: I see we would get a copy even of r-values? So yes, we can have a single constructor, but no, we can't have perfect forwarding in that case?

Comment: @wally if the argument is an rvalue, then it gets moved into the parameter. So the move constructor is called twice in total.

Comment: It looks like pass-by-value [creates a copy](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be38b7d5f9309c1e) and then performs a move?

Comment: @wally That's what I said in one of my previous comments.